# Adjust size of label to the wrapped text

Tags: css, xaml, xamarin

trying to format 2 labels.
Labels should represent title and value.
They should have position on bottom right corner.
On tablet everything looks fine, but on phone when "value" need to be wrapped. The space where it could not fit the wrapped text on the first line still stay.

So on the end, the text formatting look strange. with empty space where text cannot fit.
In this case I can imagine that size of second label is adjust to the size of longest text on line...

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label
            Grid.Column="0"
            BackgroundColor="Bisque"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="Version of Co.:"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

        <Label
            Grid.Column="1"
            BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="This is vereverevery longversiontitle."/>
    </Grid>
        
    
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

When I will set up horizontalTextAlignment on the second label to "Start" result will look like this and I will have again strange empty space.

[image]

With short text which dont need to be wrap, whole layout looks fine as I want:
[image]

**Update:**
Expected behavior:

[image]

Comment: This is the expected design , there is no enough space for the text `longversiontitle` in first line , so it comes to second line , this is why it looks so strange . What's the exact effect do you want if the long text is wrapped ? Could you provide the screen shot of that ?

Comment: I updated ticket with expected behaviour. Short story: expect that when it cannot fit and it wrap, that it will eliminate the empty space and adjust size of label which will make cover over text and not over even empty space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add one more column to your grid,

and change the position of label to 1, 2 respectively.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label
            Grid.Column="1"
            BackgroundColor="Bisque"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="Version of Co.:"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>

        <Label
            Grid.Column="2"
            BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="This is vereverevery longversiontitle."/>
    </Grid>
        
    
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Set the outer StackLayout's `Orientation` as `Vertical`.
- Add the extra column to the Grid, and set the exact width value on it .
- Set the Label's `HorizontalTextAlignment` as `End`.

##### Sample code

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                BackgroundColor="Bisque"
                FontSize="Medium"
                Text="Version of Co.:"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>

            <Label 
                Grid.Column="2"
                BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond"    
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                FontSize="Medium"
                Text="This is vereverevery   longversiontitle."/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```